# how to load gltf in three JS

Tags: three.js, gltf

I'm a beginner in ThreeJS. I want to import a cube basic from Blender in gLTF format... This is my code.

What is it missing?

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(rosa, 1);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Instantiate a loader 
        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

        function renderingScene() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        function cargarGLTF() {
            // Load a glTF resource
            loader.load('./glTF/resources/cube/untitled.gltf', function (gltf) {
                scene.add(gltf.scene);
            });
           // renderingScene();
        }
        cargarGLTF();
        controlMouse();
        renderingScene();
```

Output console

[image: Output console]

Comment: For starters, it doesn't look like you call `renderingScene` after you load your object. If you're not calling render in requestAnimationFrame (which is the standard practice, done in all threejs examples), then you need to call it after updating your scene

Comment: Here's a sample of working code that loads glTF files: [[source](https://github.com/cx20/gltf-test/blob/69a6c24333d189870fc3ae9c7faa0a01cd498eba/examples/threejs/index.js)] [[demo](https://cx20.github.io/gltf-test/examples/threejs/index.html?category=tutorialModels&model=DamagedHelmet&scale=1.0&type=glTF)]